# JavaScript share on global performance of webpages

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, web, statistics

Take a random web page with JavaScript on the web. Are there any numbers on what the share of JavaScript is on the global load/execution time?
I mean, if that share would be close to 0%, there would be no benefit in optimizing the JavaScript interpreter, nut as we all know, you can make some money with a fast interpreter :)
I guess companies like Google and Mozilla have such numbers, but I couldn't find them.

Can someone point me to some numbers?

thanks in advance

Comment: Zakas did some presentations on this topic. If I remember correctly, the mere execution of JavaScript code doesn't have a huge impact on web-page load performance (relatively speaking).

Comment: You could use Safari’s WebInspector (particularly it’s [Timeline](http://www.webkit.org/blog/1091/more-web-inspector-updates/#timeline_panel) tool) and test it on your own.

Comment: This would be a good idea if I had to measure it for a specific website, but I need some global numbers (like in this blogpost from MSDN).

Comment: @sime-vidas I will have a look at that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Performance: Profiling how different web sites use browser subsystems](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/08/30/performance-profiling-how-different-web-sites-use-browser-subsystems.aspx)

**Bringing It All Together**

> To build a fast real world browser you have to understand how different browser subsystems impact performance in real world scenarios, and you have to focus on the subsystems that matter.
>
> For AJAX sites, that means focusing on **Rendering** (*31%*), **JavaScript** (*21%*), **Formatting** (*14%*) and **Layout** (*12%*). For news sites, that means focusing on **JavaScript** (29%), **Marshalling** (*18%*) and **Rendering** (*17%*).

**Profiling News Sites**

[image: Profiling News Sites]

[image: Profiling News Sites2]

**Profiling Top AJAX Sites**

[image: Profiling Top AJAX Sites]

Comment: Thanks this was the kind of article/link I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

For most web pages, the JavaScript adds only a tiny amount of execution time to the initial "getting ready" process. In fact, it can complete its execution before images etc. have even downloaded. So yes, the impact of JavaScript on the overall initial load/execution time is often close to zero.

I don't have the numbers you're asking for, but if I did, I think they would indicate that JavaScript execution speed isn't important.

But it *is* important. Initial load/execution time isn't the whole story.

In the past, making web pages faster was all about reducing the time between the moment you enter the URL and the moment the page is rendered and ready to use. And yes, JavaScript doesn't have a major impact on this little piece of time (on most websites), and thus the browser vendors didn't worry about it too much. JavaScript engines were extremely slow, and it didn't matter much.

Now, more and more web pages are becoming rich client-side applications, with the page changing in response to the user's clicks and movements, and all this is handled by JavaScript. With applications like these, a faster JS engine makes the whole experience feel faster, not just the initial load. And the general consensus is that this trend will continue; many predict that web applications will become more popular than desktop applications for most tasks.

That's why the browser vendors are now working so hard on their JavaScript engines – to handle today's JS-heavy web apps (and tomorrow's even-more-JS-heavy web apps) faster. But it's a kind of "faster" that you can't easily measure in seconds.

Comment: For many web apps, JS also generates the entire DOM, that allows the JS to update the DOM without duplicating server side code. Thank God Chrome started moving in the right direction in regards to JS engine speed. When Chrome first came out, our time sheet application took 15 seconds to render a monthly time sheet with 4500 rows on IE. On Chrome, it was taking < 5. Now, in the latest version of chrome, < 3 secs. For a standard weekly time sheet with < 100 rows, it's sub second. I would also argue that web applications already are more popular than desktop applications.